# Migrating claims based authorization from web api in MVC5 to MVC6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-4.6

I am following these two articles [here](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html) and [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html) to get my head around how to migrate my claims based authentication and authorization from MVC 5 to MVC 6.

In MVC 5 I could use the `ClaimsPrincipalPermission` attribute as below on respective action methods

```cs
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation = "RecordManagement", Resource = "Edit")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult EditRecord(string id)
{
    //Code to
    //edit
    return Ok("Edited: " + id);
}

[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation = "RecordManagement", Resource = "Delete")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteRecord(string id)
{
    //Code to
    //delete
    return Ok("Deleted: " + id);
}
```

then build the principle object from a database query that has the key value combination of `Operation` and `Resource` during the login process
and then use the `context.Principal.HasClaim(action, resource);` call in the overridden `CheckAccess` method of the class `MyCustomClaimCheck : ClaimsAuthorizationManager` to validate access.

There doesn't seem to be a way to achieve something similar using the MVC6 framework from what I see. The only thing that seems to come close is using this line to add policies [as per docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html#adding-claims-checks)

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber"));
    }
```

But this would mean I bloat up that method with all the possible policies that are in the application. If my understanding is right this is not a very good approach.Has anyone found a workaround for using the claims based approach like it was done in MVC5?